# Django - reverse_lazy in DeleteView yields NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

New to Django and html; I want to add the possibility to delete objects from the database.

When I get to the delete confirmation template and click "Confirm", the objects gets deleted but I get this error:

> "Reverse for 'assets' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

My DeleteView includes `success_url = reverse_lazy("assets")`.  I get no error if I change that to `success_url = "/appname/assets/"`, the user gets redirected to the assets list as wanted, but I'd rather not use a hard-coded url.

Relevant code:

Models:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
    file_location = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    file_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    file_md5 = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="", blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("appname:asset_details", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename
```

Views:

```
class AssetsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "assets.html"
    context_object_name = "assets_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Asset.objects.all()

class AssetDetailsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Asset
    template_name = "asset_details.html"

class AssetDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Asset
    success_url = reverse_lazy("assets")
```

Urls:

```
#  /tams/assets/
    url(r'^assets/$', views.AssetsView.as_view(), name="assets"),

#  /tams/asset/1/
    url(r'^asset/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AssetDetailsView.as_view(), name="asset_details"),

#  /tams/asset/1/delete/
    url(r'^asset/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AssetDelete.as_view(), name="asset_delete"),
```

Asset Delete Template:

```
{% block body %}

    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ asset.filename }}"?</p>
        <input class="btn btn-link"
                       type="button" value="Cancel"
                       onclick="window.history.go(-1);"/>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm using Django 1.9.8 with Python 3.5

Comment: Please show how assets/urls.py is included into the main urls.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were just specifying a url name `assets`, but I think it might be missing `appname` as prefix(I saw you have other urls that contains the app name), maybe try:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy("appname:assets")
```

Comment: Yep that was it!  I had tried "appname/assets", next time I'll know the syntax ;-)  Many thanks!